# Predicate that will swap the first two letters in an atom in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to write a predicate which will swap the first two letters in an atom of length two or more.  Length one atoms are unchanged.

```
?- interchange(cat,X). 
X = act;
```

I am suppose to use name function to split the atom:

```
?- name(food,[X,Y|Z]).

Z = "od",
Y = 111,
X = 102 ;
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
inter(X,[]).

inter(X,[Q|W]):-
    name(X,[H,T|R]), reverse([H,T],W), !, append([W],[R],F).
```

I get this output:

```
P = [] ;

P = [_VCSF, 111, 102] ;
```

How can I improve my code to get desired output. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use `name/2` also for converting a list of characters into an atom. So try this: `name(Atom, [111, 102 | "od"])`

Comment: One issue, which you didn't mention, is that you are probably getting "singleton variable" warnings, meaning you have variables which aren't being instantiated in your logic. You should examine those warnings. At lease one of those is the reason for the `_VCSF` (an uninstantiated variable) in the answer. Also, think about your rules logically. For example, the rule, `inter(X, []).` says that for *any* atom, `X`, a valid answer is `[]`. Is that logical?

Comment: @findall The predicate `name/2` should be regarded as legacy, deprecated. Nowadays, better use the standard `atom_codes/2` or `atom_chars/2` built-in predicates.

Comment: @PauloMoura Thanks for giving me good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard `atom_chars/2` built-in predicate:

```
swap_first_two_characters(Atom, SwappedAtom) :-
    (   atom_chars(Atom, [Char1, Char2| Chars]) ->
        % two or more chars
        atom_chars(SwappedAtom, [Char2, Char1| Chars])
    ;   % one char atom
        SwappedAtom = Atom
    ).
```

Comment: My professor has asked us to use name..can u tell how can i use name to implement the above.

Comment: See my comment above: `name/2` is an old, deprecated predicate. That said, you can simply replace in my answer `atom_chars` with `name`. But if you do that, you should also rename the `Char*` variables to `Code*` for consistency.

Comment: `name/2` will give you strange results. Like `swap_(1.2,'.12')` instead of a clean error.