# Interchanging first two letters in a word using prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate which will swap the first two letters in an 
   atom of length two or more.  Length one atoms are unchanged.
  e.g. ?- interchange(cat,X). 
         X = act;
using 'name'

I am not getting idea to do this can anyone help me please.

Is it possible to transfer the letter to a variable and swapping it using third variable like in 'C' programming??

Written Code as follows:-

```
interchange(X,[]).
interchange(X,[H|T]):-  swap([A,B],W). 
swap(X,Y):- name(X,[A,B|C])-> name(Y,[B,A|C]).
```

i was not sure with my logic. I did the same thing but its not working.

i am getting my o/p as:

23?- consult(inter_change).
Warning: interchange/2 redefined
Warning: swap/2 redefined
true.
24?- interchange(cat,X).
X = [] ;
X = [_VCTC| _VCTD] ;
fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Predicate that will swap the first two letters in an atom in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323501/predicate-that-will-swap-the-first-two-letters-in-an-atom-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0):

You read the documentation regarding the [analysis and construction of atoms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=manipatom).

Then you pick a suitable built-in predicate and say something like:

```
swap_first_2( X , X ) :-
  nonvar(X) ,
  atom_codes( X , [_] )
  .
swap_first_2( X , Y ) :-
  nonvar(X) ,
  atom_codes(X,[A,B|C]) ,
  atom_codes(Y,[B,A|C])
  .
swap_first_2( X , Y ) :-
  nonvar(Y) ,
  atom_codes(Y,[A,B|C]) ,
  atom_codes(X,[B,A|C])
  .
```

Comment: `swap_first_2('',X).` fails.  And `swap_first_2(X,a)` gives an irritating answer.

Comment: @false: `''` should fail: The O.P.'s problem statement only specifies atoms of length 1 or more. As for the "irritating answer", see my amendment.

Comment: Now `swap_first_2(X, X).` silently fails - meaning there is no solution - that is incorrect. And `swap_first_2(ab,ba)` has a redundant solution